# Module ‘Snap’ does not export ‘get’

Tags: haskell, haskell-platform, haskell-snap-framework

I am trying to learn snap web framework is haskell . I am following the tutorial http://janrain.com/blog/tutorial-building-a-sample-application-with-haskell-snap-postgresql-and-the-postgresql-simple-snaplet/

I get the following error when I do cabal install and no clue what is mistake ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

I was using different version of the snap framework than given in this tutorial . Things works fine after changed the version .

Answer (score 1):

In the current version (11/18/17), you can get the `get` function from `Data.Monad.State`. So, add the following:

```
import Data.Monad.State
```

and remove

```
import Snap (get)
```